# How to pause at cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios

I have a tableView with x number of sections, each with one row.  In each row there are UIElements that take an input.  The input comes from core data.  I have previously appended the input into arrays, and then indexed into the arrays, but I want to set them directly/individually in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  Since the CD fetch takes some time to complete, I need to "pause" cellForRowAtIndexPath (until the coreData fetch has sent an NSNotification that it is finished.)
How can I pause and only set the UILabels etc when the fetch is done.  I need to do this for each section.

Any help would be very much appreciated !  Thank you.

I fear the code will just confuse, so feel free to ignore it.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    let dashboardCell = CellList.sharedInstance.dashboardCell[userIndexForItem[indexPath.section]] as DasboardCell

    dashBoardCellGlobalVariablesInstance.value = dashboardCell.cdFetchObject.queryCDValue()

    <--PAUSE AND WAIT FOR NSNOTIFICATION
    let value =  cell.contentView.viewWithTag(5) as UILabel
    value.text = dashBoardCellGlobalVariablesInstance.value
    <-- More UI ELEMENTS -->

    return cell

}
```

Comment: It's not a good performance to make a query to CD every time cellforRowAtIndexPath is called... I recommend you to fetch all objects  before reloadData is called

Comment: ahh, ok because of ReusableCell? right?

Comment: No, because a single fetch using executeFetchRequest in NSManagedObjectContext takes less time than fetching every object by separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restructure your approach. Fill each cell with the data you have, yes, but you **do not** want to block the UI while you're awaiting the notification.

When you receive the completion notification, store the data in question into your dataSource then appropriately reload the tableView data (the correct answers to how, where, when are app-dependent).

From UITableView Class Reference (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/):

Reloading the Table View

- reloadData
- reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
- reloadSections:withRowAnimation:
- reloadSectionIndexTitles

Comment: Ok, so - just go back to storing each element in arrays and indexing at cellForRowAtIndexPath?  is that the best way then?

Comment: The "right" answer depends on lots of things that are app-dependent, like how much overall data is fetched, how long an average fetch takes, how much needs to be in-memory at any one point in time, etc. For example, you can still do a lazy load if you want; put placeholder data in the fields that haven't been loaded and when the data arrives, tell the tableview to update the indexPaths that arrived. Is that the correct implementation for your user experience? I can't tell you that one.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you architect your class this way

```
Class YourClass
{
    var valueArr = [String]()
    var cdValueObjectArr = [ValueObject]()
    let totalSession = 7
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!        

    func viewDidAppear()
    {
       let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

       for i in 0...totalSession
       {
          String cdValue = cdFetchObjectArr[i].queryCDValue()
          valueArr.appendElement(cdValue)
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
              tableView.reloadData()
          }

       }
     }

    }


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    let dashboardCell = CellList.sharedInstance.dashboardCell[userIndexForItem[indexPath.section]] as DasboardCell


    if valueArr.size() > indexPath.session
    {
        let value =  cell.contentView.viewWithTag(5) as UILabel
        value.text = value[indexPath.session]

    }

    return cell
}


}
```